# PDFMake - Export multiple datatables into single PDF file with Pdfmake

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, export-to-pdf, pdfmake

I want to export multiple data tables into a single PDF file using PDFMake.
I've modified my code to generate PDF for multiple tables by taking reference from [Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/234464/datatables-plugin-print-multiple-tables-on-one-page).

But In my case the PDF is generating only for one table(last table) even though I tried to generate the content for 2 tables statically.
I want to use a way using which I can be able to export a single PDF for multiple data tables as my tables are going to be generated dynamically that means I don't know how much tables are going to be formed.

Attaching my code:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    var tables  = document.querySelectorAll('.data-table');
    //alert(tables[0].dataset.sheetname);
    var tableArr = [];
    tables.forEach((element, index) => {
      $(element).DataTable();
      tableArr.push(element.dataset.sheetname);

      //alert(element.dataset.sheetname);
    });

    $('#ExportPdf').click(function(){
      var config = {
        className:"buttons-pdf buttons-html5",
        customize:null,
        download:"download",
        exportOptions:{},
        extension:".pdf",
        filename:"*",
        header:true,
        namespace:".dt-button-2",
        orientation:"portrait",
        pageSize:"A4",
        title:"*"
      };

      var tablesConverted = {};

      tables.forEach((element, index) => {
        var dataTable = $(element).DataTable();
        //alert(element.dataset.sheetname);
        var data = dataTable.buttons.exportData( config.exportOptions );
        var info = dataTable.buttons.exportInfo( config );
        var rows = [];
        
        if (config.header) {
          rows.push($.map(data.header, function (d) {
            return {
              text: typeof d === 'string' ? d : d+'',
              style: 'tableHeader'
            };
          }));
        }
        
        for (var i=0, ien=data.body.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
          rows.push($.map(data.body[i], function ( d ) {
            return {
              text: typeof d === 'string' ? d : d+'',
              style: i % 2 ? 'tableBodyEven' : 'tableBodyOdd'
            };
          }));
        }
        tablesConverted[tables[index]]=rows;
      });
      console.log(tablesConverted);
      
      var doc = {
        pageSize: config.pageSize,
        pageOrientation: config.orientation,
        content: [
          {
            table: {
                headerRows: 1,
                body: tablesConverted[tables[1]],
            },
            layout: 'noBorders',
          },
          {
            table: {
                headerRows: 2,
                body: tablesConverted[tables[2]],
            },
            layout: 'noBorders',
          },
          
        ],
        styles: {
          tableHeader: {
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 11,
            color: 'white',
            fillColor: '#2d4154',
            alignment: 'center'
          },
          tableBodyEven: {},
          tableBodyOdd: {
            fillColor: '#f3f3f3'
          },
          tableFooter: {
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 11,
            color: 'white',
            fillColor: '#2d4154'
          },
          title: {
            alignment: 'center',
            fontSize: 15
          },
          message: {}
        },
        defaultStyle: {
          fontSize: 10
        }
      }; 
      pdfMake.createPdf(doc).download('optionalName.pdf');
    });
  });
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }

  td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
  }
```

```html
<button id="ExportPdf" type="button">Export All</button>
<table class="data-table" data-sheetname="Table 1" id="table-1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-exportname="Company">Company</th>
      <th data-exportname="Contact">Contact</th>
      <th data-exportname="Country">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-exportname="Alfreds Futterkiste">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td data-exportname="Maria Anders">Maria Anders</td>
      <td data-exportname="Germany">Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-exportname="Centro comercial Moctezuma">Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td data-exportname="Francisco Chang">Francisco Chang</td>
      <td data-exportname="Mexico">Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-exportname="Ernst Handel">Ernst Handel</td>
      <td data-exportname="Roland Mendel">Roland Mendel</td>
      <td data-exportname="Austria">Austria</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table class="data-table" data-sheetname="Table 2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-exportname="Company">Company</th>
      <th data-exportname="Contact">Contact</th>
      <th data-exportname="Country">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-exportname="Alfreds Futterkiste">Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td data-exportname="Maria Anders">Maria Anders</td>
      <td data-exportname="Germany">Germany</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table class="data-table" data-sheetname="Table 3">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-exportname="Company">Company</th>
      <th data-exportname="Contact">Contact</th>
      <th data-exportname="Country">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-exportname="Centro comercial Moctezuma">Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td data-exportname="Francisco Chang">Francisco Chang</td>
      <td data-exportname="Mexico">Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-exportname="Ernst Handel">Ernst Handel</td>
      <td data-exportname="Roland Mendel">Roland Mendel</td>
      <td data-exportname="Austria">Austria</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```